# Returning the active member of a union using a function within it

Tags: c++, c++14, unions

or within its outer struct/class if anonymously nested. (<- to add to the title without making it longer).

I want to be able to simply call a function and get the member of a union being used (by any means, e.g returning it, modifying a parameter etc...), not the type (or an identifier for the type) but the actual member , or a non-void pointer to it. Is there a way to do this in modern (c++14) c++?

Comment: You cannot do this. This information isn't stored.

Comment: You can store it by only allowing setters to modifying the union's members. (Registering the type passed).

Comment: Have you look at `boost::variant` and its `static_visitor` ?

Comment: @KerrekSB Interestingly, it must be stored when working with unions inside constant expressions. You can observe that on e.g. Clang. I'm not sure whether you could extract the information, though...

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, it is what I am looking for. You should post it as a proper answer though, for clearness.

Comment: [Eggs.Variant](https://github.com/eggs-cpp/variant) is far more appropriate for a modern compiler than Boost.Variant IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/libs/variant/), the current value/type is stored. You may apply a `static_visitor` to the variant as for example:

```
#include "boost/variant.hpp"
#include <iostream>

class times_two_visitor : public boost::static_visitor<>
{
public:

    void operator()(int & i) const
    {
        i *= 2;
    }

    void operator()(std::string & str) const
    {
        str += str;
    }
};


int main()
{
    boost::variant<int, std::string> u("hello world");
    std::cout << u; // output: hello world

    boost::apply_visitor(times_two_visitor(), u);
    std::cout << u; // output: hello worldhello world
    u = 21;
    boost::apply_visitor(times_two_visitor(), u);
    std::cout << u; // output: 42
}
```